# Check if another action filter attribute is being used in action in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, actionfilterattribute

I have few custom action filters like

```
public class CustomFilter:ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
     //Some task
  }
}
```

---

```
public class CustomFilterNew:ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
     //Some task
  }
}
```

---

In my action method

```
[CustomFilter]
[CustomFilterNew]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

> Lets say CustomFilterNew exactly does opposite of CustomFilter.

In such case how to prevent one filter action from executing another filter action lets say **CustomFilterNew** should prohibit executing **CustomFilter**

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `filterContext.Result` property to any non-null value will stop execution of later filters. So if your first filter sets `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(...)`, the second filter and action method will never be run.

There are many ways to do that as follow

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
         filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index");
  }
```

OR

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    //Check your condition here
    if (true)
    {
        //Create your result
        filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
    }
    else
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

OR

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
    ...
    if (needToRedirect) //your condition here
    {
       ...
       filterContext.Result = new RedirectToAction(string action, string controller)
       return;
    }
    ...
 }
```

Another thing here i have to mentioned how to set `Order` of filter works you can give an `Order` to `Action Filters` as follow to execute filters in order

```
[FilterOne(Order = 1), FilterTwo(Order = 2)]
```